# I am working on a SFM in matlab and the estrelpose function is giving me a headache

Tags: matlab, structure-from-motion

I am doing a SFM work on MATLAB and I am using the estrelpose function, and it´s giving me 4 different relative pose, shoundt it give just 1 relative pose value?
I already checked the calibration of the camera, the matched features and they are correct.

I already checked the calibration of the camera, the matched features and they are correct.